# Generar loading en React Native

Tags: react-native

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del logged en el que mando el textloading a infoUser para que lo aplique le asigno el texto pero no se ejecuta el loading y me genera un mensaje indicando que "setTextLoading" es de solo lectura.

```
  import Loading from "../../components/Loading";

export default function UserLogged() {
    const[userInfo, setUserInfo]=useState({});
    const[reloadData, setReloadData]=useState(false);
    const[isLoading, setIsLoading]=useState(false);
    const [textLoading, setTextLoading]=useState("");
    const toastRef=useRef();

    useEffect(()=>{

        (async()=>{
            const user=await firebase.auth().currentUser;
            setUserInfo(user.providerData[0])
        })();
        setReloadData(false);
    },[reloadData])

    return(
        <View>
            <InfoUser 
            userInfo={userInfo}
             setReloadData={setReloadData} 
             toastRef={toastRef}
             setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
             setTextLoading={setTextLoading}
             />
            <Button 
            title="Cerrar sesión"
            onPress={()=>firebase.auth().signOut()}
            />
        <Toast ref={toastRef} position="center" opacity={0.5}/>
        <Loading  text={textLoading} isVisible={isLoading}/>
```

Este es la clase que donde se manda el loading para que genere el mensaje y al momento de correr la aplicación en mi dispositivo móvil al momento de hacer el cambio del perfil ya me genera el siguiente mensaje de error y no me carga:

> Error: "setTextLoading" is read-only

Y seguidamente este mensaje:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: "setTextLoading" is read-only]

```
    import React from "react";
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import {Avatar} from "react-native-elements";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import * as permissions from "expo-permissions";
import * as imagePicker from"expo-image-picker";


export default function InfoUser(props){
    const {
    userInfo:{uid,displayName,email,photoURL},
    setReloadData,
    toastRef,
    setIsLoading,
    setTextLoading
    }=props;
   console.log(props);

   const changeAvatar= async()=>{
    const resultPermission=  await permissions.askAsync(permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    const resultPermissionCamera=resultPermission.permissions.cameraRoll.status;    
       if(resultPermissionCamera==="denied"){
        toastRef.current.show("se necesitan aceptar los permisos de la galeria ");
    } else {
        const result= await  imagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing:true,
            aspect:[4,3]
        })
        if(result.cancelled){
            toastRef.current.show("cerro la galeria de imagenes sin seleccionar ninguna imagen");
        }else{
            uploadImage(result.uri, uid).then(()=>{
                updatePhotoUrl(uid);
            })
        }
    }

   }
   const uploadImage= async(uri, nameImage)=>{
    setTextLoading=("actualizando avatar");
       setIsLoading(true);
       const response =await fetch(uri);
       const blob = await response.blob();  
       const ref = firebase
       .storage()
       .ref()
       .child(`avatar/${nameImage}`);
       return ref.put(blob);

   };

   const updatePhotoUrl = uid =>{
    firebase
       .storage()
       .ref(`avatar/${uid}`)
       .getDownloadURL()
       .then(async result =>{
        const update ={
            photoURL:result
        }
        await firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile(update);
        setReloadData(true);
        setIsLoading(false);
       }).catch(()=>{
        toastRef.current.show('Error al obtener la foto de perfil');
       })

   }
```

Comment: Intenta en la medida de lo posible poner todo el codigo y los errores en formato texto

Comment: El error se debe básicamente porque estás intentando reasignar una constante, lo puedo comprobar por esta línea `setTextLoading=("actualizando avatar");` quizá quitando el `=` funcionaría, o al menos no te saldría más ese error

Comment: efectivamente era por eso funciono correctamente muchas gracias por la ayuda